# C: Error using malloc and realloc on array of structs

Tags: c, struct, malloc, free, realloc

I am trying to dynamically allocate memory for a algorithm on a graph. This is my code broken down to the problem:

```
typedef struct
{
    int id;
    int color;
} node_t;

unsigned int max_n = 2;
node_t* node_malloc = malloc(sizeof(node_t) * max_n);
node_t* nodes = node_malloc;

if(atoi(left_node) > max_n)
{
    max_n = (size_t) atoi(left_node);
    nodes = realloc(nodes, sizeof(node_t) * max_n);
}
```

For max_n < 9 the realloc works - when max_n is 9 or greater, "free(): invalid pointer:" is thrown.

```
free(node_malloc);
```

When free(node_malloc) is called after a realloc happened it throws "free(): invalid next size (fast)"

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: What does it mean "doesn't work"?

Comment: Yea sorry, added that. I does work when it didnt reallocate, but not when it reallocated.

Comment: it also depends on how you write to array. see nothing good in `atoi()` and all this. and put to account that you dont care to pack  `struct`'s so there're many gaps and it will definitely turn out bad when something custom is done on that.

Answer (score 2):

What's happened is that after the `realloc` call, the pointer value in `nodes_malloc` is no longer valid.  If `realloc` cannot extend the current buffer in place, it will allocate space for a *new* buffer, copy the contents of the old buffer to it, and then free the old buffer, which is obviously what happens when you extend by more than 9 elements.

Use `nodes` as a *temporary* target of the `realloc` call - if it's not `NULL` (meaning the `realloc` succeeded), assign it back to `nodes_malloc`:

```
nodes = realloc( nodes_malloc, sizeof *nodes * max_n );
if ( nodes )
{
  nodes_malloc = nodes;
}
else
{
  // realloc failed
}
```

Comment: Yes and put it into an own function. You probably need to use it more than once. ;)

Comment: Thanks. I did as you said, and free(node_malloc) works fine now. Now tho: When i call realloc(nodes_malloc, sizeof *nodes * 29); i get "free(): invalid size" !

Answer (score 1):

You have this:

```
node_t* node_malloc = malloc(sizeof(node_t) * max_n);
node_t* nodes = node_malloc;
```

After that, the pointers `node_malloc` and `nodes` both point to the very same memory.

But after the first call to `realloc` that's no longer guaranteed. In fact it's almost *certain* that `nodes` will point somewhere else, and the `node_malloc` pointer will be invalid.

Attempting to `free(node_malloc)` will then lead to *undefined behavior*.

---

On a related issue, you should never assign back to the pointer you pass to `realloc`. If `realloc` fails it will return `NULL`, but the old memory allocation will remain valid. If you reassign back to the same pointer, you loose the original memory and have a memory leak. Always use a temporary variable, and check for failure (`NULL`).

Comment: OP should probably replace `free(node_malloc)` with `free(nodes)`.